# Do we lose readers by migrating questions from ChristianSE to BH?

Tags: discussion, migration

Some questions that deal strictly with hermeneutics clearly need to be migrated to BH, but I worry that readers may not follow other questions to BH because the atmosphere here is more technical/intellectual, off-putting to general readers. So I wonder:

1. How many ACTIVE users are there on BH compared to CH.se?  I see that the *overall* numbers are similar, but do most Christianity.se users jump over to BH to see what's going on here if a question is migrated?
2. What guidelines do moderators use in deciding what needs to get migrated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation-traffic), Biblical Hermeneutics gets 1472 visits/day. Christianity gets 798 visits/day. So if anything questions that get migrated are slightly more likely to be seen.

As [I just explained at the Christianity.SE Meta](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7335/6071) the two sites have mostly complementary scopes. Few questions would be on-topic on both sites.

Comment: Out of the 1472 visits/day I wonder how many are repeat visitors that are just obsessed with the site? I notice that the other site has a thousand more users.

Comment: very useful answer! I'm surprised to learn that BH gets so many more visits because my impression is that it more narrow in scope and kind of scary to non-experts. First impressions can be deceiving I guess... at least to me.

Comment: + 1  ...by the way, does an upvote on Meta actually convey any benefit to the recipient?

Comment: @DanFefferman There's no reputation, but it does signify agreement or appreciation of the post.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How many ACTIVE users are there on BH compared to CH.se?...

The other mod who moderates both sites already answered a lot of this. I'll only add that BH is younger and only recently got out of beta and still doesn't have a logo yet. It was founded by many of the same users.

> 2. What guidelines do moderators use in deciding what needs to get migrated?

Decisions to migrate are part of the process of deciding whether to close or re-open a post and is generally seen as a friendly alternative to closing.

It's largely about "how to interpret Bible" vs "institutional doctrine".

On BH.SE we look at specific Bible passages or specific interpretation methods. Sources would likely be Bible verses, explanations while quoting Bible verses, historical setting, and known methods of interpreting Bible and/or literature.

C.SE doesn't address how to theology on our own, but looks for what Roman Catholics often refer to as "Church doctrine" or any belief or theological teaching held by a known Christian institution or denomination. Sources would likely be things like catechisms, theologians, history, et cetera.

When a question aims at the theology development process, it's generally considered off-topic on BH. This often catches questions with multiple Bible verses because multiple verses are usually the fuel for constructing SysTheo.  I tend to be tolerant and welcoming if those Bible verses are related through a narrative theme or development of a specific character in the Bible because characters and narratives are literary/hermeneutical topics. "Theology of Biblical writers" would be a stretch for me, but would need to truly be about the historical setting of the writers or original audience, et cetera.

I also consider the answers, especially an accepted answer, and sometimes comments to determine what the topic of a question was. If a rather brief question comes along, then the OP accepts a theological answer, then I'll determine that the question had a theological intention from the start and move toward closing it. But, by that time, other moderators and users have probably already raised several flags against it. If not, I'll probably leave it alone.

Whenever I see a question as off-topic, but still valuable for anyone seeking answers, I'll ask myself if it could fit within the scope of "institutional doctrine found in Christian history" and move to migrate to C.SE if it does. But, that rarely happens and when it does, another mod or user has probably already raised the same suggestion.

Usually, these decisions get discussed among us moderators. While we comment from different angles, each of us would usually make the same open/close/migrate decision in the end.

Comment: thanks for a thorough answer... and thank y'all moderators for what must be a mostly thankless task.

Comment: @DanFefferman Thanks to you for being a big part and making it worth it